# Is there a way to allow standard users to change assignedto in a task

Tags: administration, profile

How can i set to allow standard users to change the assigned to field in a task. As an administrator i can change the owner, is there a way to allow standard users to do the same?

Or its restricted by license ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User would either have to own the record the task is related to or be above the owner in the role hierarchy.

The only other way would be to grant them Modify All data permission on the object level.

Comment: Thanks.. modify all data is too much powers for standard user